# using dictionaries in swi-prolog

Tags: dictionary, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm working on a simple web service in Prolog and wanted to respond to my users with data formatted as JSON. A nice facility is `reply_json_dict/1` which takes a dictionary and converts it in a HTTP response with well formatted JSON body.

My trouble is that building the response dictionary itself seems a little cumbersome. For example, when I return some data, I have data id but may/may not have data properties (possibly an unbound variable). At the moment I do the following:

```
OutDict0 = _{ id : DataId },
( nonvar(Props) -> OutDict1 = OutDict0.put(_{ attributes : Props }) ; OutDict1 = OutDict0 ),
reply_json_dict(OutDict1)
```

Which works fine, so output is `{ "id" : "III" }` or `{ "id" : "III", "attributes" : "AAA" }` depending whether or not `Props` is bound, but... I'm looking for an easier approach. Primarily because if I need to add more optional key/value pairs, I end up with multiple implications like:

```
OutDict0 = _{ id : DataId },
( nonvar(Props) -> OutDict1 = OutDict0.put(_{ attributes : Props }) ; OutDict1 = OutDict0 ),
( nonvar(Time) -> OutDict2 = OutDict1.put(_{ time : Time }) ; OutDict2 = OutDict1 ),
( nonvar(UserName) -> OutDict3 = OutDict2.put(_{ userName : UserName }) ; OutDict3 = OutDict2 ),
reply_json_dict(OutDict3)
```

And that seems just wrong. Is there a simpler way?

Cheers,
  Jacek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks mat and Boris for suggestions! I ended up with a combination of your ideas:

```
dict_filter_vars(DictIn, DictOut) :-
    findall(Key=Value, (get_dict(Key, DictIn, Value), nonvar(Value)), Pairs),
    dict_create(DictOut, _, Pairs).
```

Which then I can use as simple as that:

```
DictWithVars = _{ id : DataId, attributes : Props, time : Time, userName : UserName },
dict_filter_vars(DictWithVars, DictOut),
reply_json_dict(DictOut)
```

Comment: It's good that you have solved it with these inputs! The question still somehow remains though: Why even create a dict when you already have the list you need? Take into account that each time you use a dict, it makes your application less portable, because dicts are not a standard feature of Prolog...

Comment: Good point, although I'm less concerned about the portability at the moment. The nice thing about dict is that it keeps keys unique, so mapping to JSON objects is more natural. Note that despite the JSON standard allows non-unique keys, many libraries do not, so it's better to keep them unique.

Comment: You don't need the parenthesis around `Key=Value` in the first argument of your `findall`.

Comment: @Boris :-)  even better. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of messing with dictionaries, my recommendation in this case is to use a **different predicate to emit JSON**.

For example, consider [**`json_write/2`**](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=json_write/2), which lets you emit JSON, also on current output as the HTTP libraries require.

Suppose your representation of **data fields** is the common `Name(Value)` notation that is used throughout the HTTP libraries for option processing:

```
Fields0 = [attributes(Props),time(Time),userName(UserName)],
```

Using the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) `include/3`, your whole example becomes:

```
main :-
        Fields0 = [id(DataId),attributes(Props),time(Time),userName(UserName)],
        include(ground, Fields0, Fields),
        json_write(current_output, json(Fields)).
```

You can try it out yourself, by plugging in suitable values for the individual elements that are *singleton variables* in the snippet above.

For example, we can (arbitrarily) use:

```
        Fields0 = [id(i9),attributes(_),time('12:00'),userName(_)],
```

yielding:

```
?- main.
{"id":"i9", "time":"12:00"}
true.
```

You only need to emit the suitable **Content-Type** header, and have the same output that `reply_json_dict/1` *would* have given you.

Comment: That looks neat, great suggestion, thanks. At the moment, I'm a little stuck with dictionaries, though. Will try to judge how much it costs to redo my code in your way. Cheers, Jacek

Comment: Great! Note that the necessary changes are extremely local: Even if all the rest of your code uses dictionaries, you can output the values in the way I outlined, by simply building a list *instead* of a dictionary.

Comment: @Jacek You can make a dictionary of of the filtered list with `dict_create(D, _, Fields)` or add the elements of the list to an existing dict with `D = D0.put(Fields)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one step if you use a list to represent all values that need to go into the dict.

```
?- Props = [a,b,c], get_time(Time),
   D0 = _{id:001},
   include(ground, [props:Props,time:Time,user:UserName], Fs),
   D = D0.put(Fs).
D0 = _17726{id:1},
Fs = [props:[a, b, c], time:1477557597.205908],
D = _17726{id:1, props:[a, b, c], time:1477557597.205908}.
```

This borrows the idea in mat's answer to use `include(ground)`.